# virtualenv error on creating a new virtual environement

Tags: python, virtualenv

when i want to create a new python venv, i use this command:

```
python -m virtualenv -p=D:\python_v2\versions\3.8.3\python.exe D:\python_v2\venvs\DataScience
```

and it worked fine since i got my new pc.

i've installed python and the virtualenv module but when i use the exact same command i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\remic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 52, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "C:\Users\remic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 51, in install
    for name, module in self._console_scripts.items():
  File "C:\Users\remic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 118, in _console_scripts
    entry_points = self._dist_info / "entry_points.txt"
  File "C:\Users\remic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 105, in _dist_info
    raise RuntimeError("no dist info")  # pragma: no cover
RuntimeError: no dist info
created virtual environment CPython3.8.3.final.0-64 in 828ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=D:\python_v2\venvs\DataScience, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\remic\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local\pypa\virtualenv\seed-app-data\v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

if someone know anything about this issue, please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [seems to be a bug regarding very long paths](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1769) (which I found by searching for "no dist info" in the Virtualenv issue tracker).

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\...` ends up being too long, it looks like.

Unless you can shorten the paths, the workaround seems to be to add `--seeder=pip` when creating the virtualenv.